# Excel - dynamic sums using Index

Tags: excel, indexing, sum

I'm having a problem with formula that is supposed to return a cumulative of values for particular months. The data looks like this:

[image]

I'm trying to make a formula that calculates a sum of from January to the month entered under "Month" cell. So if a user types i.e. 3, the formula should give a sum of Jan, Feb and March.
I prepared a formula to get a value from particular cell but don't know how to do it as a cumulative:

```
=SUM(INDEX((B5:D5;F5:H5);1;B9;2))
```

where B9 is the numer of Month. I've tried to use an array formula but didn't work.

Any hints?

Comment: Are those dates or text strings in row 5?

Comment: Which row exactly? All numbers are integers

Comment: Are those dates formatted like names of months or are they text

Comment: They are just text, but i need to use a number of month, January = 1, February = 2 etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, to get cumulative sum you can use following formula:

```
=SUM(B5:INDEX(B5:D5;1;B9);F5:INDEX(F5:H5;1;B9))
```

Months must be in ascending order and without gaps.

[image]